# animate scroll in both direction

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Hello guys I have a list in which there is an anchor tab. The option that is clicked it is highlighted by applying the CSS.

The problem is that I want to animate it like if by default the option is at `option1` and when I click on `option4` it should have a scrolling effect and then go to option 4 and apply the CSS effect on it and on the it's way to option 4 all the options that come in between the option1 and option4 should animate for like a second or half a second. and vice versa.

**HTML**

```html
<ul style="list-style-type:none" id="freeddom" class="idTabs">
  <li><h5><strong>about us</strong></h5></li>
  <hr class="aboutUs-line"/>
  <br/>
  <li id="our_Story_det" ><a href="#option1" class="selected"><span>| &nbsp;</span>  op1</a></li>
  <br/>
  <li><a href="#prime_Choice" class="option2"><h6>op2</h6></a></li>
  <li><a href="#prime_Differece" class="option3"><h6>op3</h6></a></li>
  <li><a href="#prime_Differece" class="option4"><h6>op4</h6></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="option1"> Hello option1</div>
<div id="option2">helloo option2</div>
<div id="option3">option3 </div>
<div id="option4">option4 </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
ul#freeddom li a.selected h6 {
  color: white!important;
  margin-left: 4px;
  background: black;
  /*border-left: 1px solid white;*/
}
```

one thing more I'm using idTabs jquery plugin for the tabs and ir applies selected class to the option that is currently active but that class does not have any effect

Comment: Do you mean like tabs?

Comment: @MoshFeu I made tabs but now I also want the content to have a scroll effect as I explained in the description

Comment: You can use plugins such as http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/

Comment: @MoshFeu this does not have a scroll effect

Comment: What do you mean? Can't you see that you click on other tab the content sliding?

Comment: @MoshFeu no I can't see it

Comment: You can see the video.. https://vid.me/StgD

Comment: @MoshFeu oh I see you are talking about this. My requirement is not this it's like I explained I want to scroll over the list. Like if op1 is selected and I click on op4 then it should smoothly scroll over to op4 and all the options that come in between it like op2 and op3 they should highlight too for like a second or two

Comment: OK, and do you have to use `idTabs`?

Comment: @MoshFeu well at first I was using ui-tabs but the html structure was being disturbed due to which I had to use idTabs

Comment: @MoshFeu do you have any idea how can I accomplish it

Comment: I can show without using a plugin, just jQuery. Is that OK?

Comment: @MoshFeu if it works for me than that would be great

Comment: @MoshFeu can you please tell me how can you do it with jquery

Comment: Yes, but it's take me time to do this..

Comment: @MoshFeu ok take your time

Comment: Have you see my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very basic tabs widget with the animation you looking for. Of course that you need to customize it with your style etc. But it's definitely a start.

```js
var tabsWidth;
var content = $('.content-inner').width(function() {
  var elm = $(this);
  tabsWidth = elm.width();
  return elm.children().length * tabsWidth;
});

setTimeout(function(){
  content.css('transition', 'all .3s ease');
});

var tabs = $('.idTabs li').click(function(){
  var elm = $(this),
      index = tabs.index(elm);
  
  content.css('transform', 'translateX(' + -(index * tabsWidth) + 'px)')
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;  
}

.idTabs {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}

.idTabs li {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 10px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-bottom-color:#fff;
  background:#fff;
  margin-bottom:-1px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.content {
  border:1px solid;
  position:relative;
  overflow-x:hidden;  
  background:#fff;
}

.content-inner {
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
}

.content .tab {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="freeddom" class="idTabs">
  <li>about us</li>
  <li class="selected">tab1</li>
  <li>op2</li>
  <li>op3</li>
  <li>op4</li>
</ul>
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-inner">
    <div id="option1" class="tab">About us</div>
    <div id="option2" class="tab">Hello option1</div>
    <div id="option3" class="tab">helloo option2</div>
    <div id="option4" class="tab">option3 </div>
    <div id="option5" class="tab">option4 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/vaguka/edit?html,css,js

Comment: My pleasure;) Good luck.